# accessing radio button with same name in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following code in my view. it has two radio buttons with same name. it works fine in controller where i can access it form collection using radio button name which gives me the selected Yes or No value
so if user selected "No" in form i will access it form["rbc"] and it gives me value of "No"

Although this is not case in jquery, i cant access this radio button to check whether user has selected Yes or No. please suggest me how can i achieve it in jquery.

I am assigning each field a class "validate"if mandatory field is "Yes" otherwise empty. in order to validate the controls from jquery(client end)

Current jquery code iterate all the radio buttons. but i need it to iterate one time for radio button having same name only once.

**Controller**

```
        signup.Controls = new List<MembershipControls>();

        foreach(var controlItem in _membershipcontrols.Table.ToList())
        {
            signup.Controls.Add(new MembershipControls()
            {
                Caption = controlItem.Caption,
                Content = controlItem.Content,
                ControlType = controlItem.ControlType,
                GroupTitle = controlItem.GroupTitle,
                Mandatory = controlItem.Mandatory == "Yes" ? "validate" : "",
                Name = controlItem.Name,
                UserId = controlItem.UserId
            }); //modify mandatory field to assign class "validate" and empty to not validate
        }




        signup.Groups = new List<Groups>();
        signup.Groups = _groups.Table.ToList();

        return View("Signup", signup);
```

**View**

```
          @foreach (var groups in Model.Groups)
            {
                    <label style="font-weight:bold">@groups.GroupTitle</label>

                    <div style=" border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;padding:5px">

                    @foreach (var row in Model.Controls.Where(r => r.GroupTitle == groups.GroupTitle))
                    {
                        <div style="padding:7px">

                             @if (row.ControlType == "Single Line Text")
                             {
                                <label>@row.Caption</label>
                                <input type="text" name="@row.Name" class="@row.Mandatory" />
                             }
                             else if (row.ControlType == "Multi Line Text")
                             {
                                 <label>@row.Caption</label>
                                 <textarea name="@row.Name" class="@row.Mandatory"></textarea>
                             }
                             else if (row.ControlType == "Yes/No Choice(Radio Buttons)")
                             {                            
                                <div>     
                                    <label>@row.Caption</label>
                                    &nbsp                     
                                    <input type="radio" name="@row.Name" value="Yes" class="@row.Mandatory"/> &nbsp Yes                             
                                    &nbsp
                                    <input type="radio" name="@row.Name"  value="No" class="@row.Mandatory"/> &nbsp No
                                </div>
                             }
                             else if (row.ControlType == "Checkbox")
                             {
                                 <div>
                                    <input type="checkbox" name="@row.Name" class="@row.Mandatory"/> @row.Caption
                                 </div>
                             }
                             else if (row.ControlType == "Date")
                             {
                                 <div>
                                     <label>@row.Caption</label>
                                    <input type="date" name="@row.Name" class="@row.Mandatory"/>
                                 </div>
                             }
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
                }
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#signupform').submit(function ()
     {
        $(".validate").each(function () {                
            if ($(this).is("input[type=radio]")) {        

               alert($(this).attr('name'));
              // here is the logic to check whether user has selcted Yes or No

            }
        });
   });
});
```

Comment: your radio buttons doesn't have validate class???

Answer (score 2):

Use as

```
 $('input[name="rbc"]:checked').val()
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/1L7xy8s9/)

Comment: Easy to find Amit appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid pseudo selectors in jQuery ([type=radio]) they have bad performance. Use a class selectors. Put a class to your radios, then do this:

```
$('.my-class:checked').val();
```

If you don't want to use the :checked directly you can use it as an is

```
$('.my.class').each(function(){
     if ( $(this).is(':checked') ) { /* magic */ }
});
```

Comment: i have modified the code. basically i am already assigning a class to mandatory fields in order to validate them from jquery. also control names are coming from server side. so i dont know the control name either. i am only accessing the control using class name "validate".

Comment: So lets suppose there are two radio buttons as a group inside one division. i need to accesss which one user has selected Yes or No

Comment: its iterating all radio buttons in jquery. i only need to access it ones against each radio button having same name.

Answer (score 0):

You should get the `:checked` items only for your radio buttons:

```
$(function () {
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        $('.validate:checked').each(function () {
            var name = $(this).attr('name');
            var value = $(this).val();
            alert(name + ' : ' + value);
        });
    });
});
```

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2yL1zw8c/1/).

Comment: the link you suggested works fine if we already know the name of radio button. but what if we are iterating class and accessing the control. please see my modified code and suggest

Comment: that's working for only checked radio buttons. what if user has not checked one of the radio button. then it wont show it. i need to check all whether user has selected no or yes or none of them.